# Prove that $f_n$ does not converge pointwise

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

If $$f_n=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{z^3}$$ on $E:=\{|z|\leq17\}$, does it converge pointwise?

I know that it does not, since as $n\to\infty$, $f_n\to\infty$ independent of $z$, but how do I convey this formally? Or is this sufficient?

Comment: is this a real valued function?

Comment: No it is complex

Comment: So $f_n(z)=\dfrac{\sqrt n}{z}$ ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by converge, it converges in the Riemann sphere to $\infty$, but if you are dealing with just complex numbers then note that $f_n(1) \to \infty$, so it cannot converge to any $w \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that $f_n$ is defined on $F:=E\setminus \{0\}$. Second let $z\in F$ then

$$f_n(z)=\frac{\sqrt n}{z^3}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\pm\infty$$
hence the sequence $(f_n)$ is divergent.